# Custom EditText with ScrollView like behaviour?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, custom-component

i need to make a Custom EditText which scrolls as fast, or has the same scroll-behaviour like a scrollView.

Can someone give me some instructions how i can make this, or has someone made it already?

I would really appreciate if someone could post some Code, or a whole CustomEditText with this function.

I'm sure a lots of people search for this.

I tried to do the EditText into a ScrollView but this causes lots of problems with the selection, ...

Perhaps someone knows how to add line-numbers too?

I hope to get an answer from someone out there ;).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: What issues with selection did you encounter and on what device/platform version? EditText within a ScrollView is fairly common.

Comment: As soon as you placed the curser at position A with your finger, it jumps the most times to position B (random position) without any other action. At the moment i had to solve it, that i save the position on click and reset it a half second / second later... It would be far cleaner with a custom EditText and i'm sure hundreds of devs would like to have this solution

Comment: What platform version and device are you observing this behavior on? Compare the behavior you're seeing with the message text area in Gmail's Compose activity when you write a new email. This is an EditText inside a ScrollView and on a Nexus S running Android 2.3 or Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0 it does not display the behavior you describe. Can you post your layouts/code/a video of the issue? You're not trying to have both the EditText and ScrollView each scroll independently, right? The general way to do this is to have the EditText height WRAP_CONTENT and let ScrollView do the scrolling.

Comment: I had it on a HTC Desire S (2.2-2.3.7), the emulator, and an Acer Iconia Tab A500 (3.2) And yes my edittext is wrap_content with a min_height... Perhaps someone (or you) know which classes need to be overridden with the classes of a listview to get a better scrolling behavior?

Comment: Putting this into a ScrollView should be fine but ListViews and EditTexts don't mix well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a listview for this custom edittext? If you do have, you can try using this setFastScrollEnabled(true);

Comment: EditText widgets inside ListView items tend to have issues with view recycling that makes putting them in ListViews a bad idea, and even if that weren't the case setFastScrollEnabled only enables/disables the fast scrolling thumb that appears along the edge of a list to allow the user to scroll across large distances quickly. It is unlikely to be relevant here.